# filter model using manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django

I've got these models :

**work.py**

```
class Work(models.Model):
  ...
  network = models.ManyToManyField(Network,related_name='network')
```

**network.py**

```
class Network(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users")
```

In my **views.py** I got this class-based generic ListView

```
class WorkList(PermsMixin, ListContextMixin, ListView):
model = Work
# Here I want to filter queryset
```

What I want to do is to filter the queryset such that the logged in user is in the network users.

I tried many things, for example

```
 queryset = Work.objects.all()
 queryset.filter('self.request.user__in=network_users')
```

But I got this error:

```
 ValueError : too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* the way to write queries. Typically you pass to a `.filter(..)` *named* arguments, these follow a "*language*" that specify *what* you want.

In your case, you want - if I understand it correctly - *all* the `Work`s for which there exists a *related* `Network` that belongs to that `User`, you do this with:

```
Work.objects.filter(network__users=self.request.user).distinct()
```

Here ***two* consecutive underscores (`__`)** are used to see "*through*" a relation. In case of a one-to-many relation, or a *many-to-many* relation, it is sufficient that *one* path (a path from `Work` through `Network` to `user`) exists.

The **`.distinct()`** should be used if you want to only return different `Work`s: if you do not use this, the same `Work` object can be in the queryset *multiple* times, since there can be *multiple* `Network`s that belong to the given `user` and are part of that `Work`.

> **Extra remark**: you define the `related_name`s exactly the same as the field name, for example:
>
> ```
> network = models.ManyToManyField(Network,related_name='network')
> ```
>
> But the `related_name` is *not* the name of the relation you define there, the related name is the *reverse* relation: the name of the *implicit* relation you have defined between `Network` and `Work`. So that now means that you obtain a queryset of `Work`s by writing `some_network.network`, which does not make sense. You typically thus give it a name like:
>
> ```
> network = models.ManyToManyField(Network,related_name='work')
> ```